# Windows 8.1 on Mac Pro tower (late 2011). Wifi is slow

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, wifi-driver, mac-pro

Yes, I do run Windows on my Mac Pro. Not in bootcamp mode, not in virtual machine - cleanly installed.

I can't figure out the problem with slow connection on WiFi.

I've updated the drivers - first tried those that come with bootcamp (Windows action center suggested to use those), but them didn't help, then I found official Broadcom v6.31.223.1 - these seemed to be latest and felt sorta a bit faster

Also I've changed `netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled`

and still it is darn slow. What else can I try?

UPD: It looks it's affecting only web browsing, for example speedtest.net shows similar speeds that would my MacBook with OS X installed show.

Web though is slow - takes couple of seconds to start loading a page

Comment: turning off "Protected Mode" in IE and disabling ipv6 feels like improved it a bit. Although still kinda slow...

Comment: Sounds like you're having slow DNS lookups rather than slow Wi-Fi.